# How do i fix this function code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am trying to iterate though three functions but get this error: NameError: global name 'dash' is not defined. How do i fix it
This is the code:

```
def draw():
    name = input('Please type here: ').lower()#.split()
    if name == 'what draw':
        print('draw here')
    else:
        dash()

draw()
def paint():
    name = input('Please type here: ').lower()#.split()
    if name == 'what paint':
        print('paint here')
    else:
        draw()

paint()
def erase():
    name = input('Please type here: ').lower()#.split()
    if name == 'what erase':
        print('erase here')
    else:
        paint()

erase()
def dash():
    name = input('Please type here: ').lower()#.split()
    if name == 'what dash':
        print('dash here')
    else:
        erase()

dash()
```

Comment: At the risk of repeating what the error message already tells you, `dash` is not defined anywhere in the code you have posted.

Comment: Can someone more familiar with pyhthon comment on why this might be tagged `functional-programming`? I can't see any use of higher-order-functions, nor meta-programming of any kind.

Comment: about the Error...is there a way, i may ask of fixing this? Thank you.

Comment: You could start by defining `dash`.

Comment: @wakamdr you can either: 1. remove the call to `dash`; or 2. actually define `dash`

Comment: my apologies, def dash(): was not include in the earlier posting. See the edit

Comment: @David-SkyMesh I think it's pretty clear this is a new user that didn't know functional programming was a specific style of programming, and thought it was just using functions.  I think just removing that tag would have been enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As currently written, your code:

1. Tries to call `dash()` before that function has been defined; and
2. Keeps asking the user to re-enter their input until they happen to enter the correct input while in the correct function.

This seems unwise. You can fix both by separating the input from the functions:

```
# function definitions here

while True:
    name = input('Please type here: ').lower()

    if 'dash' in name:
        dash()
    # repeat for other functions
    elif 'quit' in name:
        break
    else:
        print("Don't know that name.")
```

Answer (score 4):

you are trying to use it before its defined.

```
def paint(): 
   ...

def draw():
   ...

def dash(): 
   ...

def erase():
   ...


draw()
paint() 
erase() 
dash()
```

Comment: this works well BUT only prints with draw()...is it because its the first one called?..u listed draw(),paint(),erase() and dash() in that order. If i substitute draw() with paint() the paint is called and the rest are not iterated over

Comment: @wakamdr you asked how to fix the error you're getting, If you want someone to review your code this isn't the place for that.

Comment: cool man i was just suggesting something i noted. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the *line number* the error is happening. It is written in the exception.
But I think that your problem might be here:

```
def draw():
  name = input('Please type here: ').lower()#.split()
  if name == 'what draw':
     print('draw here')
  else:
     dash()
draw()
```

You call draw() but draw() will call dash() and dash is not defined yet